# save calling cost in file android programmatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to save phone calling cost in text file, when we are calling to any person and after

disconnect, the phone call cost summary shows in front of the mobile with ok button,

i don't know it is possible or not, please tell me that Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this link. http://android2011dev.blogspot.in/2011/08/get-android-phone-call-historylog.html

Comment: Want to get call summary of phone calls?

Comment: no i want to save that call summary in database file it is possible

Comment: Yes...if you get the call summary as a string and then save to it in datbase. Also refer a link which asha has given.

Comment: @kirti now you are able to chat in room...so enter in room so specialist of android developer gives a solution.

Comment: check with "Hello World" group.